# what is the first schema checked?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am a little confused right now. Can someone answer me with a simple answer to this question.

I have a user [user_test] and has [db_owner] role assigned to him for one database [database_test]. 
The user's default schema is [user_test] and almost all objects from the [database_test] are created under schema [user_test]. In the database exist 3 more objects with schema [dbo]

The user has rights to both schemas: [dbo] and [user_test] without explicitly specifying them in select statements in front of objects reference.

What is the first schema checked by SQL when an object is called by user [user_test] ?

I mean, If [user_test] issues a select for an object from dbo schema (without schema in front), will SQL first check in it's default schema specified and then in dbo?

thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With SQL Server 2005 & 2008 the first schema that is searched is the users default schema.

from [SQL Server Best Practices – Implementation of Database Object Schemas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd283095%28v=sql.100%29)

> **Default Schema**
>
> Users can be defined with a default
> schema. The default schema is the
> first schema that is searched when it
> resolves the names of objects it
> references.

and

> creating the base tables in
> the dbo schema will enable table
> objects to be referred to without an
> explicit schema name. This is because
> an object will be located by searching
> the default schema first, followed by
> the dbo schema. So:
>
> `SELECT * FROM Table1`
>
> Will assess the following statement first:
>
> `SELECT * FROM <defaultschema>.Table1`
>
> If it cannot find the object, the server will assess the following statement:
>
> `SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1`
>
> The assessment process can be improved by using either the fully qualified name
> or the DEFAULT_SCHEMA option described earlier. By setting a value for
> DEFAULT_SCHEMA for the user, the server will check the DEFAULT_SCHEMA
> first, removing an unnecessary ownership checking process.
>
> *This can improve performance considerably on heavily utilized systems.*

Default Schema was introduced in SQL Server 2005 [Upgrading to SQL Server 2005 and DEFAULT_SCHEMA setting](https://web.archive.org/web/20160115003025/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mssqlisv/archive/2007/03/23/upgrading-to-sql-server-2005-and-default-schema-setting.aspx)